# java.lang.Throwable: stack dump when Facebook login

Tags: android, facebook, dump

Here is the place my error occur when I using Facebook login:

```java
session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback).setPermissions(Arrays.asList("email")));
```

Here is the error log:

```
java.lang.Throwable: stack dump
    at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:489)
    at com.facebook.Session.addCallback(Session.java:813)
    at com.facebook.Session.open(Session.java:1234)
    at com.facebook.Session.openForRead(Session.java:471)
    at FacebookAuthFragment.onCreateView(FacebookAuthFragment.java:62)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:450)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

java.lang.Throwable: stack dump
    at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:489)
    at com.facebook.Session.addCallback(Session.java:813)
    at com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper.onResume(UiLifecycleHelper.java:108)
    at FacebookAuthFragment.onResume(FacebookAuthFragment.java:96)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:1547)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:978)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:450)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have declared appid in AndroidManifest and String.

Is there someone know what's happen? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There had error when we decode Facebook session. After we fixed that problem, problem was solve.